# Can SagaData be manipulated before the saga handler fires using NServiceBus

Tags: nservicebus

Using NServiceBus (v6), is there a way to ensure that a property is set in the SagaData object before the Saga Handler for a message is fired?

Our environment is multi-tenant so I want to ensure that the correct CustomerId is used for db access etc.. and that developers don't forget to pull this value from the incoming message/message header.

For example given this saga data ...

```
public interface ICustomerSagaData : IContainSagaData
{
    Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
}

public class SomeProcessSagaData : ICustomerSagaData
{
    // IContainSagaData and other properties removed for brevity ...

    #region ICustomerSagaData properties

    public virtual Guid CustomerId { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

... and the following Saga ...

```
public class  SomeProcessSagaSaga :
    Saga<SomeProcessSagaData>,
    IAmStartedByMessages<StartProcess>
{
    public async Task Handle(StartProcess message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        // How do I ensure that Data.CustomerId is already set at this point?

    }

    // ConfigureHowToFindSaga etc ...
}
```

I initially tried inserting a behaviour into the pipeline e.g.

```
public class MyInvokeHandlerBehavior : Behavior<IInvokeHandlerContext>
{
    public override async Task Invoke(IInvokeHandlerContext context, Func<Task> next)
    {
        // Ideally I'd like to set the CustomerId here before the 
        // Saga Handler is invoked but calls to ...     
        //      context.Extensions.TryGet(out activeSagaInstance);
        // return a null activeSagaInstance

        await next().ConfigureAwait(false);

        // This is the only point I can get the saga data object but
        //  as mentioned above the hander has already been invoked
        ActiveSagaInstance activeSagaInstance;
        if (context.Extensions.TryGet(out activeSagaInstance))
        {
            var instance = activeSagaInstance.Instance.Entity as ICustomerSagaData;
            if (instance != null)
            {
                Guid customerId;
                if (Guid.TryParse(context.Headers["CustomerId"), out customerId))
                {
                    instance.CustomerId = customerId; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

... but this only allows access to the SagaData instance **after** the handler has been fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer your question directly Data.CustomerId is not going to be set when you handle StartProcess messages. You will need to set that with the id coming off of the message.

```
public async Task Handle(StartProcess message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
{
    Data.CustomerId = message.CustomerId;
}
```

That being said your sample above is missing a crucial piece which is the code for determining how a saga can be looked up for continuation of processing:

```
protected override void ConfigureHowToFindSaga(SagaPropertyMapper<SomeProcessSagaData> mapper)
{
    mapper.ConfigureMapping<StartProcess>(message => message.CustomerId)
        .ToSaga(sagaData => sagaData.CustomerId);
}
```

Each time you send a message type that is handled by a saga you need to have the `ConfigureHowToFindSaga()` method configured so it can look up the previously started saga to continue processing with. So in essence you are going to **start a new saga** for every customerid you send with a `StartProcess` message. You can read more about it here: https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/

So the real question now is do you really need to be using a saga at this point? The sample only seems to be handling one type of message so do you really need to be saving the state of CustomerId? The overhead of the saga isn't necessary in your sample and I believe a regular handler would be just fine based on the example above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ColinPear. Couple things 1) I understand Data.CustomerId isn't going to be set there ... that's what I'm trying to see is even possible. Reason being that if we can handle it in the pipeline then every dev who uses the `IContainSagaData` will get it set for "free". 2) `ConfigureHowToFindSaga` is mentioned in the comments. I'd removed it for brevity as (_I thought_) it was't crucial to explaining the problem. 3) The code sample above isn't real code but a highly trimmed down fake scenario for readability. Our saga(s) are much more involved than that.

Comment: Ok. So in essence you are trying to populate the customerId without having to put it on the message?

Comment: Currently the customerId is on every message in the headers and am looking to copy that to the saga data "automatically"... and by that I mean in the pipeline somewhere.

Comment: Setting values in the pipeline is an overly complicated way to avoid having to write one line of code in your Saga. That being said I dont think you can achieve what you want for two reasons: 

1) The saga does not exist at this point. It hasn't been created so what would the saga data record be tied to?


2) If it does exist you would have to rewrite all of the code for looking up sagas and put it in the pipeline. You would also need to include the business logic for how to look it up (a.k.a ConfigureHowToFindSaga()) in the pipeline as well mixing business logic and infrastructure code.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but you need to make sure your behaviour executes after the SagaPersistenceBehavior.

In your IConfigureThisEndpoint implementation:

```
    public virtual void Customize(EndpointConfiguration configuration)
    {
        configuration.Pipeline.Register<Registration>();
    }

    public class Registration : RegisterStep
    {
        public Registration()
            : base(
                stepId: "AuditMutator",
                behavior: typeof(AuditMutator),
                description: "Sets up for auditing")
        {
            this.InsertAfterIfExists("InvokeSaga");
        }
    }
```